# How would I make this program automatically restart at random times?

Tags: google-apps-script, discord

I'm making a discord bot that will output random messages at random points in time (ranging between 5-20 minutes or so), but I cannot figure out how to make it repeat. How would I do that? I'm not very good at organizing it, but everything else works so far. It posts the message when I run it, but I don't know how to make it do it on it's own.

````
function postMessageToDiscord(message) {




  const phrases = [
   'list thing'
  ];

function randomPhrases(phrases) {
   return phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
}

var x =randomPhrases(phrases);

         message = message || x;








  var discordUrl = '';
  var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

  var params = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);

  Logger.log(response.getContentText())



}```
````

Comment: Search the documentation for time based triggers.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can [programatically create triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) to schedule your next execution.

Your function would behave in the following manner:

1. Delete previous triggers
2. Output a random message
3. Create a new time-based trigger with a value between 5 and 20 minutes from now

Hope this helps!